# why the ajax can't store the data to the database?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

[PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuf8n.png)
My goal is when i press enter the input data will save to the database.

**The Controller:**

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request){
    $data = Message::create([
        'from' =>  Auth::user()->id,
        'to' => $request->receiver_id,
        'message' => $request->message,
        'is_Read' => 0,
    ]);
    $data->save();
}
```

**The form:**

```
<div class="card-footer">
<form id="message_form">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text attach_btn"><i class="fas fa-paperclip"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="message" id="message_input" class="form-control type_msg" placeholder="Type your message...">
    </div>
</form>
```

**The ajax code:**

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.input-group input', function (e) {
        var message = $(this).val();
        var url = '{{ url('message') }}';
        // check if enter key is pressed and message is not null also receiver is selected
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && message != '' && receiver_id != '') {
            $(this).val(''); // while pressed enter text box will be empty

            var datastr = "receiver_id=" + receiver_id + "&message=" + message;
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: '/message', // need to create this post route
                data: datastr,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
                },
                complete: function () {

                }
            })
        }
    })
```

**The Route:**

```
Route::post('message', [ConsultationController::class, 'sendMessage']);
```

And than the result the data not in the database, and there is no error notification. How can i solve this? Please Help :)

I try to delete the If statement in the ajax code, and this is happened (500 ... (Internal Server Error))[PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKr5L.png):

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/message 500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   consultation?message=adfadf:399
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:2
v.handle    @   jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: Try to set Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded when sending your request

Comment: Is your controller parsing the string that you are posting correctly?

Comment: and also try `$request->input('receiver_id')` not `$request->receiver_id`

Comment: @Lk77 im sorry, i dont understand "Try to set Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded when sending your request", can u explain more specifically?

Comment: @SeanLawton I think it's right

Comment: @Lk77 I have try this $request->input('receiver_id'), but its doesnt work

Comment: is your method even called ? try to add a dd because this should work, forget what i said about the content-type, jquery does that for you it's sending the payload fine

Comment: Try adding a try catch to handle errors

Comment: @Lk77 where i can put the dd? Sorry im new about all of this

Comment: @SeanLawton Sorry im new about the codeing, can u tell me how?

Comment: Im sorry guys because I don't understand u guys. Hope all of u can help me :)

Comment: well, for example in your sendMessage, you can put a `dd('test');` just to see if your method is called, my guess is perhaps there is something missing like the csrf token and your request does not pass through, what is the status code of the request ? 200 ? 422 ?

Comment: nothing happened when i put dd, and i have put the csrf in the js top of the ajax code 
`$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});`

Comment: well the 'test' string should appear in the response of the request, if not there is something wrong, check the payload of the request and the body of the response with the devtools

Comment: i still not find the problem, in the console or network tab there is no error, but i found there is no POST Request Method running when i press enter

Answer (score 0):

Did you added your columns in $fillable property in Message model ?

Comment: yes i put the fillable

Comment: Then just check that your values are coming or not in controller using dd($request->request->all());

Comment: but i have try the dd, its not showing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, you just need to notes that on every post / put / delete request, laravel require csrf token to validate. You can read more about this security on [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token).

You need to add this on your ajax request.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: '/message', // need to create this post route
                data: {
                    receiver_id,
                    message,
                },
                headers: { // Add this
                 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 
                   $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
                },
                complete: function () {

                }
            })
```

Comment: i added this on the first line of the JS tag `$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });`
i have try yours but its not working too

Comment: well it should perform the same.

What error did you get from console? have you check your network tab?

Comment: there is no error in the console

Comment: is the ajax request perform successfull on network tab?

Comment: i updated my answer, try change your code on ajax data

Comment: oh no, i think the post ajax not working, i dont find the POST Request Method in the network tab

Comment: then you should debug this on your javascript level, are your condition run successfull? are your code inside if condition block is executed?

Comment: its runs without error, i have try to command the if statement, the network tab display "POST ... 500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: POST ... 500 Internal Server Error are not helping, try to post the error trace also so people know whats going on at your server.

Comment: this is what u mean? `jquery.min.js:2 
 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/message 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ consultation?message=asdasdad:377
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2,`